# Как добавить в карусель динамический товар?

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Всем привет! Есть у меня подключенная owl-carusel, хочу чтобы она выводила динамически добавляемые товары из виджета со списком, т.е. чтобы li вставлялись на место div - как это можно сделать? Код привожу

```js
$(".add_to_cart_button").click(function() {
  $('.cart_list li').each(function() {
    $('#owl-example').append('<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>');
  });
});
```

```html
/* Карусель */
<div class="container" id="carousel">
  <h3>ДОБАВЛЕННЫЕ БЛЮДА</h3>
  <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
    <div>
      <li>Товар 1</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>Товар 2</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>Товар 3</li>
    </div>
    <div>
      <li>Товар 4</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

/* Виджет с корзиной */
<div class="widget_shopping_cart_content">
  <ul class="cart_list product_list_widget "></ul>
  <!-- end product list -->
</div>
```

Comment: неужели никто не знает как? хотя бы подскажите как все должно выглядеть: список ul с li поместить внутрь карусели по какому-то условию или наоборот? ведь, если li обернуть в divы, то список не будет списком или я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.cart_list li').each(function(){
    $('#owl-example').append('<div>'+$(this).html()+'</div>');
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Это имелось в виду?

Comment: да, суть такая, но что-то все равно не получается.. Здесь между классами скорее всего нужна точка, ".cart_list.product_list_widget li", но все равно не работает..

Comment: Не, точка не нужна. Я подправил. Достаточно было указать один класс. Я не обратил внимание, что там указано два класса. Скопировал сначала его, как один... В общем, по идее достаточно будет вот так: $('.cart_list li')

Comment: ну сначала вашу функцию нужно поставить на срабатывание при клике на кнопку "В корзину" + нужно создать обработчик на удаление также.

Comment: @Maks Devda, повесил событие на кнопку, но оно как-то неправильно отрабатывает - каждый раз пересчитывает заново и корзина пополняется в арифметической прогрессии

Comment: @Вася 
вот такой код повесь 

`$('#owl-example').append('<div>'+$('.cart_list li:last')+'</div>');`

вместо старого варианта

Comment: @Maks Devda неа, таким способом только 
    <div>[object Object]</div> пишет..в карусели пишет.. или вы может имели ввиду внутрь 
    $('.cart_list li').each(function() 
вставить?

Comment: @Вася вот такой код повесь `$('#owl-example').append('<div>'+$('.cart_list li:last').html()+'</div>');` сори не посмотрел, там еще html() нужно было.

Comment: @Maks Devda, да теперь добавляются списки в слайдер, но прикол вот в чем: элементы списка отображаются на сайте, а вот слайдера нет.., хотя разметка вся присутствует..очень странно..

Comment: в коде @DES же отображался и список и слайдер, но получается, что инфа дублировалась и там и там, и в коде слайдера имелись такие слайды, как "пустая корзина", а если элементы списка скрывать, то скрывались и слайды карусели - как это можно поправить уже совсем запутался..

Comment: Не совсем понятен последний комментарий. Но если нужно, чтобы НЕ дублировалось, то можно добавить, например, $(this).remove(); и удалять li из "cart_list" после переноса. То есть, код будет таким, как я подправил выше...

Comment: @DES, плохо - при вашем коде даже с $(this).remove(); продолжает дублироваться или что вы имели ввиду под "и удалять li из "cart_list" после переноса."? что-то еще?

Comment: @Maks Devda, твой код все равно создает дубликаты..

Comment: @Maks Devda, твой код все равно создает дубликаты..теперь понял - не прокатывает, т.к. при повторном добавлении товара он остается на своем месте в списке, только ему добавляется +1